# Entity Relationships Break the GET Request - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've recently added a `@ManyToOne` & `@OneToMany` association on two of the `@Entity`s in my Spring MVC Project.

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private BookCategory category;

}

@Entity
public class BookCategory{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Book> books;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "getAllBooks", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Book> getAllBooks(){
    return bookRepo.findAll(); // Native Spring JPA method
}
```

Before including the joins, I could easily populate a `List` of Books (without their BookCategories) and send them to the client as a JSON response.

However, after including the joins my asynchronous request fails and I get the following error in Chrome

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

On IE:

```
Unterminated string constant: {description: "...
```

Also in Chrome I see

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:
```

The request itself runs fine, returning a 200, and the response *looks* like normal JSON array of objects. Any ideas why this might be occuring?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it Lazy loading or Eager for joined collection?

Comment: @notanormie I haven't defined any FetchType, so whatever the default is

Comment: Do you use POSTMAN, Curl or any REST Client? Try it once and see what output you are getting.

Comment: @aksappy I ran with Advanced REST Client - Returned a 200 but also returned an unparseable array of objects

Comment: Can you convert your DAO Objects into a simpler DTO structure and send the DTO in the RequestMapping?

Answer (score 1):

posible problem could be endless json.
each book contains a category, ecach category contains same book, that contains category, that contains the same book and soo on

```
book: {
  category: {
    book: {
      category: {
        book: {
    .. and so on
```

so you mapper can convert you object to a json-like string

**EDIT:**
you can fix it using Views.

create `BookView` class and `BookCategoryView` class

```
public class BookCategoryView {

// contains all nessesery fields: id, name ..
// contains getters and setters
// DOESN'T contain book field

}

public class BookView {
  // contains all nessesery fields: id, name ..
  // contains getters and setters

  // here add List<BookCategoryView>
}
```

if you convert you entity objects to this view object, that does not have endless circle dependencies than you can omit that error

**MORE INFO:** usually such objects call DTO's(Data Transfer Object). So if you named them `BookDTO` and `BookCategoryDTO` everything will be clear

Comment: This seems like it could be the issue. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @KuraiBankusu, in my answer I add the easiest solution

Comment: Thanks for the response. it seems that @JsonIgnore resolved this issue as well (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue). I'll report back if I find anything missing

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding `@JsonIgnore` to my `BookCategory` Entity.

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
private List<Book> books;
```

Description:

```
@JsonIgnore - Marker annotation that indicates that the annotated method or field 
is to be ignored by introspection-based serialization and deserialization functionality.
```

As Oleh pointed out this response looked like an endless recursive JSON response. Including the annotation prevents this and returns the appropriate response